# Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS problems with characters

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I downloaded an Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS ISO and checked the md5sum. I burnt it on an USB drive with Unetbootin. After that I tried Ubuntu from Live USB and I got a problem with characters. There are missing and bad characters. Some characters flicker when I move the mouse cursor on them.

I have a Msi h97 pc mate, i5-4460 and a Gtx 750ti.
Here's a photo :
[image]

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Edit: Bad English :)

Comment: Anyone? Same issue with 15.10. I solved adding "nomodeset" in boot options but my maximum resolution is now limited to 1280x720. There are a lot of similar posts about the bad driver support with Maxwell nvidia cards.